# In Netsuite how can I include a list of tracking numbers in an email generated from an Item Fulfillment?

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I need to send a custom "Order Shipped" email from an Item Fulfillment record in Netsuite. I am making the email template using freemarker. I would like to include the tracking numbers for packages associated with the Item Fulfillment in the email.

I have tried using:

`<#list transaction.package as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumber} </#list>`

However when I send the email template from the communication tab of an item fulfillment (that has multiple packages with tracking numbers) I see nothing in the email.

I then tried:

`<#list transaction.package as pkg>TEST</#list>`

and still saw nothing (I would have expected to see "TEST" as many times as there are packages), so it seems like the list of packages is empty, even though I can see many packages in the UI for this Item Fulfillment.

How can I get the tracking numbers onto the email template sent from an Item Fulfillment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `transaction.packagefedex` to refer to the package and `transaction.packagefedex.packagetrackingnumberfedex` for the tracking number

Answer (score 1):

To get all tracking numbers on an Item Fulfillment, you should account for all the possible tracking numbers. There are three that NetSuite uses:

1. `transaction.package`
2. `transaction.packageups`
3. `transaction.packagefedex`

The actual tracking link is referenced in with FreeMarker like this:

1. `<#list transaction.package as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumber}</#list>`
2. `<#list transaction.packageups as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumberups}</#list>`
3. `<#list transaction.packagefedex as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumberfedex}</#list>`

And some sample code that could prove helpful to list all the tracking numbers is below. Note a couple of things in the example:

- I list each package tracking number and use the FreeMarker `?is_last` tag to determine if this is the last tracking number (so put a period) or if there are more (so put a comma and space). This logic isn't perfect, since you might list UPS packages and come to the end and not put a space and then list Fedex packages and you'd have the first Fedex link right next to the last UPS link. I guess you could say this assumes only one carrier is used per fulfillment :)
- For the non-UPS, non-Fedex links, I use an `if` statement and reference the `shipmethod` field to determine what the link should be.
- I've auto-formatted the code for readability, but you can obviously remove newlines/whitespace to get the paragraph to show properly.

```html
We have made a shipment against your PO ${transaction.createdfrom.otherrefnum}, with tracking number(s) <#list
    transaction.packagefedex as pkg> <a
        href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr=${pkg.packagetrackingnumberfedex}">${pkg.packagetrackingnumberfedex}</a>
    <#if pkg?is_last>
        <#else>,
    </#if>
</#list>
<#list transaction.packageups as pkg><a
        href="https://www.ups.com/track?tracknum=${pkg.packagetrackingnumberups}">${pkg.packagetrackingnumberups}</a>
    <#if pkg?is_last>
        <#else>,
    </#if>
</#list>
<#list transaction.package as pkg>
    <#if transaction.shipmethod?contains("DHL")><a
            href="https://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB=${pkg.packagetrackingnumber}&amp;brand=DHL">${pkg.packagetrackingnumber}</a>
        <#else>${pkg.packagetrackingnumber}
    </#if>
    <#if pkg?is_last>
        <#else>,
    </#if>
</#list>
```