# Netsuite - Workflow Email Sends on Item Fulfillment - Unable to include Tracking Numbers

Tags: netsuite

Overall project:

Sending automated emails from Netsuite when select orders are being fulfilled.

Utilizing workflow functionality to send 'on create' of an item fulfillment based on custom email field on the sales order being empty or not.

All emails are being sent as expected the only issue I'm encountering is on the email template - I cannot get the tracking numbers to print. I have searched extensively and found different ways other users were able to get this done but isnt working on my end. The email returns a null field for all of the below - even though the item fulfillment form does have these tracking numbers:

```
salesorder.linkedtrackingnumbers
record.linkedtrackingnumbers
transaction.linkedtrackingnumbers

 <#list transaction.package as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumber} </#list>
```

When I look at the item fulfillment xml I can see the package tracking number I'm trying to extract but am just lost on how I get this field into the email template.

Thanks

Comment: Events: On Create, Trigger Type: After Record Submit?

Comment: Have you seen splemp's answer to the related question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433310/in-netsuite-how-can-i-include-a-list-of-tracking-numbers-in-an-email-generated-f#